# Automatic new line and indentation in vim when inside braces?

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

For example, if I'm coding jQuery in vim, and I have this in insert mode ("|" is the current cursor position):

```
$('#something').click(function(){|})
```

...and I hit enter, I would like to get this:

```
$('#something').click(function(){
    |
})
```

...while currently, I'm getting this:

```
$('#something').click(function(){
|})
```

The same thing happens with function definitions in PHP. Is there a way to automatically insert the extra new line and indent the cursor position when hitting enter inside braces like that?

(Apologies if this has been asked before - it seems like a common request but I searched for awhile and couldn't find it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up just hardcoding this into .vimrc, as follows

```
" Make it so that a curly brace automatically inserts an indented line
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<Esc>O<BS><Tab>
```

It would seem like the `<BS><Tab>` parts aren't necessary, but for some reason it wasn't indenting correctly like the O command usually does, so I had to add it.

Comment: hey is there any way to make so that if we dont actually press `Enter` the cursor does not stay behind the curly bracket?  

ex:  
`if(true) {`

if I press `foo = 10` it will make   
`if(true) f{oo = 10}`

Answer (score 2):

Just install [auto-pairs plugin](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) and be happy.

Comment: That's a great plugin, I replaced delimitMate for it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [javascript.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1936) which (almost) does what you want for JavaScript code.

There's also a [php.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=604), but I didn't test it.

Comment: Hmm, I am already using javascript.vim with no success. Did you have to do anything extra to get the extra newline thing working?

Comment: @Mike: First, do you use the same version as mentioned there and did you put it in the right place (mine is in ~/.vim/indent). Second, do you have `set smartindent` and `autoindent` in your .vimrc?

Comment: yes and yes. If you feel like taking a look: https://github.com/mikecrittenden/vimstuff (you don't have to of course :))

Comment: @Mike: Hmmm, it appears I also have [detectindent.vim](http://github.com/ciaranm/detectindent) in my ~/.vim, but I'm not sure whether it will make a difference.

Comment: @Mike – And in my /usr/share/vim/vim73 there's a file named indent.vim, but that's a file of Vim itself, so it already should be included.

Answer (score 0):

My version is similar but uses `<C-o>` instead of `<Esc>` since it would trigger validation by JavaScriptLint.vim.

Also, I don't really want every `{}` to be on multiple lines so it's mapped to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↩</kbd>.

```
inoremap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>
```